# How can I convert an 18digit number to a human-readble date in Excel?

Tags: excel, powershell

How to convert 18 digits value into human-readable date in excel?

As per the title, how to covert 18 digits numbers (eg.634019142119225390) into human-readable date in excel?

In Powershell the following seems to be the way to do so:

```
$timeStamp = 634019142119225390/ 10000000
$epochTime= [datetime]"01/01/0001 00:00:00"
$epochTime.AddSeconds($timeStamp)
```

Comment: As an aside: You can simplify the PowerShell code to: `[datetime] 634019142119225390`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do below:

Here’s an example of how you can do that:

First, divide the timestamp value by 10,000,000 to convert it from 100-nanosecond intervals to seconds.
Then, subtract 62,135,596,800 from the result to convert it from the .NET epoch (January 1, 0001) to the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).
Finally, add the result to the DATE(1970,1,1) function to get the final date value.
Here’s an example formula that converts the timestamp value in cell A1 into a human-readable date:

```
=DATE(1970,1,1)+((A1/10000000)-62135596800)/86400
```

**Copy this**

This formula divides the timestamp value in cell A1 by 10,000,000 and subtracts 62,135,596,800 to convert it from the .NET epoch to the Unix epoch. It then adds the result to the DATE(1970,1,1) function and divides by 86,400 (the number of seconds in a day) to get the final date value.

You can then format the resulting cell as a date.

Please check if i get this right